# Who is this giant spider creature?

Tags: dc, character-identification

Who is this giant spider creature?

I don't want to call him a *villain* as he's in a picture with [Justice League Dark](http://www.comicvine.com/justice-league-dark/4060-58596/) and could very well be a temporary member or ally.

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with DC but an image search leads to Vol 19 (or 1 9) of Justice League Dark, and the synopsis mentions Dr Mist being caught by a giant spider in a temple. Other JLD images don't show the spider thing so it might just be a monster they deal with. Not good enough for an answer but maybe it will help someone get better results ,:)

Comment: It's a villian then..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 maybe by the end of the issue he was their friend? Lets not judge this poor fellow too soon

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433, a villain or just an incidental monster, I'd imagine. Certainly the synopsis makes no big thing of the spider (as I would imagine it would for a proper villain, though it also doesn't mention the spider has a human face or anything so it might not even be that) but I'm not at all familiar with DC (that's Constantine on the cover, and I never even knew he was DC haha) so that's just an external guess.

Comment: @MacCooper Well, *Hellblazer* is published under the Vertigo imprint, so that's understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spider-creature on the cover of [**Justice League Dark #9**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_League_Dark_Vol_1_9) doesn't actually appear in the issue. The creature is probably meant to represent the overall threat of the issue, which are a variety of demonic creatures summoned by Felix Faust throughout the issue. Also, at one point near the end, JLD member Doctor Mist finds himself stuck in a giant spider web and must be freed by the others. However, whatever horror made the web is never shown.

We later find out that

> Doctor Mist is actually a mole working FOR Felix Faust. Given this fact, it's entirely possible that Doctor Mist created the web himself and no actual spider creature existed.

Comment: Isn't there a trope specifically for comics with characters on the front that don't actually appear in the comic itself? Very frustrating!

Comment: @Daft - I don't know if there's a term for it, but it's pretty common for comic book covers to be somewhat misleading. In fact, you can go back as far as the 40's and find it.

Comment: [Wolverine Publicity](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WolverinePublicity)